# Find Method in Linked List does not work with some numbers

Tags: java, list, linked-list, find

I don't know why find() method does not work for some numbers. Here is the code.
I'm talking about finding element in Double Linked List.

```
public DLLNode<E> find(E o) {
        if (first != null) {
            DLLNode<E> tmp = first;
            while (tmp.element != o && tmp.succ != null)
                tmp = tmp.succ;
            if (tmp.element == o) {
                return tmp;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Element does not exist in a list");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        }
        return first;
    }
```

Comment: What is data type of number? what is `tmp.elememt`? I am pretty sure you are just comparing the references instead of the data itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your issue is with :

```
    if (tmp.element == o) {
        return tmp;
    }
```

which is comparing objects using reference equality, not value equality.  You want to use `.equals` for that.  You mention it works for some numbers, which I'm guessing means you have a `DLLNode<Integer>` in your test - you're probably just running into the fact that the JVM caches a small subset of Integer objects (I think between -127 and +128) so those appear to work when using `==`.

Comment: you forgot one reference equality

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `equals` instead of `==`

`==` compares references, ex:

`new Double( 2d ) == new Double( 2d )` will be false,

but `new Double( 2d ).equals(new Double( 2d ))` will be true.

```
public DLLNode<E> find(E o) {
        if (first != null) {
            DLLNode<E> tmp = first;
            while (!tmp.element.equals(o) && tmp.succ != null)
                tmp = tmp.succ;
            if (tmp.element.equals(o)) {
                return tmp;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Element does not exist in a list");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        }
        return first;
    }
```